# Dynamic fields on jsp from database using Struts2 ,Hibernate

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery

Using Struts2:

I have a table in my database with fields(2 text boxes and 2 dropdown). And my jsp renders them correctly with respective values. Now What I want is whenever I add any field manually in my database how dynamically I can render it on my jsp using Struts2. Do I need to use ajax???? or How should I proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Updated :
I have a table in my database with 2 columns, Name of Label (Name, Age etc) and Type of Input Element (textbox, dropdown etc)
Now I want whenever I add any field manually or through some form to database, I need to render it dynamically on my JSP using Struts 2.
The corressponding Input element should be shown on the jsp.

Comment: you mean moment it got added to the database it should show one more field in the UI..?

Comment: Yes exactly....@ Umesh Awasthi

Comment: well,than you need to send some kind of signals to the view that DB has been updated else there is no way to tell UI about it.

Comment: You don't need to use Ajax, you just need to retrieve the field names from the DB and build appropriate UI for each. The easiest approach would use a map keyed by field name to hold the form values.

Comment: @DaveNewton Hi. I have a table in my database with 2 columns, Name of Label (Name, Age etc) and Type of Input Element (textbox, dropdown etc) Now I want whenever I add any field manually or through some form to database, I need to render it dynamically on my JSP using Struts 2. The corressponding Input element should be shown on the jsp.  will using map help ?? How???

Answer (score 1):

From your question and comments you'll need comet type functionality. If this is an intranet application where you can control the version of the browser then web sockets are an option.

On the back end there are some considerations. Namely is your application the only means of updating the database or are there multiple applications updating the database. In the first case you can have each client register a listener and then each update flags all listeners. Looking at how a chat server works would address all these issues.

If there are multiple applications which contribute to the database then you could pole for changes or have the database notify you of changes, by creating update triggers which invoke some sort of notification mechanism. The problem being this will be different between databases and so is a more complicated scenario.

Some reading:

Basic Comet:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

Talks about comet vs web sockets and the atmosphere framework (a comet framework which will use websockets if available): 
http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/websockets-or-comet-or-both-whats-supported-in-the-java-ee-land/

If using JPA their callback and listeners might be useful: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event

Comment: This is my scenario.I have a table in my database with 2 columns, Name of Label (Name, Age etc) and Type of Input Element (textbox, dropdown etc) Now I want whenever I add any field manually or through some form to database, I need to render it dynamically on my JSP using Struts 2. The corressponding Input element should be shown on the jsp.

Comment: I don't think the OP is saying it needs to update the screen as the DB is updated, I just think they want to list form fields in the DB. Could be wrong, it's hard to tell.

Comment: @DaveNewton : thanku....ya u are ryt...in short I want to make customised form. (like Dynaforms in struts1) how can i achieve this in struts2....do we have any standard library for it. I have searched a lot

Comment: @DaveNewton : you have already mentioned ,i can use map for that.Can u pls elaborate.

Comment: Well then, this answer is radically off topic then.